# what is the meaning of that syntax in (probability)

Tags: probability

A test for a rare disease claims that it will report a positive result for 99.5% of people with
the disease.
what is the meaning of the whole syntax the ?(positive result , people have the disease ... etc) full explanation for the syntax please.

and after answering that shall you also try to explain the solution of that question please

thanks in advance

A test for a rare disease claims that it will report a positive result for 99.5% of people with
the disease, and will report a negative result for 99.9% of those without the disease. We
know that the disease is present in the population at 1 in 100,000. Knowing this
information, what is the likelihood that an individual who tests positive will actually have
the disease?

Comment: It means that when they test people for the disease, there is a $99.5$% chance that they correctly determine whether someone is infected, _given that they have the disease_.

Comment: that mean that there is .5% people that actually have the disease but they did not recognize them am I right

Comment: Yes, there is a $0.5$% chance that someone with the disease has a test result saying that they do not.

Comment: and for the negative part in the problem in the question it mean that will correctly determine  99.9% from the people that they don`t have the disease and the remaining .1% will recognized as infected by mistake

Comment: Yes, you have it.

Comment: I upvoted from -1 back to 0.  Conditional probability problems are tricky/convoluted enough that it seems overly harsh to punish no preliminary work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the comments, it looks like the OP has got it.  However, the problem is convoluted enough that I think it is worthwhile to elaborate.

A denotes the event that the person tests positive. 
B denotes the event that the person has the disease.

You want $p(B/A) = \frac{p(AB)}{p(A)},$ by Bayes theorem. 
$p(AB) = \frac{1}{10^5}\;\times\; \frac{199}{200}.$ 
$p(A) = \{\frac{1}{10^5}\;\times\; \frac{199}{200}\} + \{\frac{10^5 - 1}{10^5}\;\times\; \frac{1}{1000}\}.$